# Error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line # 50: Binary XML file line # 50: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android

I want to use flexible ui in my mainActivity. When I run the application on my emulator log show error:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line # 50: Binary XML file line # 50: Error inflating class fragment.

mainActivity

```
public class ParentSpaceMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,ChildHomeworkList.Callbacks, ChildHomeworkAdd.Callbacks , ChildHomeworkUpdate.Callbacks {

private  ChildHomeworkList mChildHomeworkList = new ChildHomeworkList();
private  ChildHomeworkAdd mChildHomeworkAdd = new ChildHomeworkAdd();



//Constants
private static final String TAG = ParentSpaceMainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
// We instantiate just one time fragments during the life of the activity.




FragmentManager fm  = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft; // = fm.beginTransaction();
Fragment mFragment = null;
Fragment mHomeworkList=null;
Fragment mFragmentListChild = null;
Fragment mFragmentChat = null;
Fragment mFragmentMyAccount = null;
Fragment mFragmentMyFamily = null;

private DatabaseReference mRef;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;
private OnDisconnect onDisconnectRef;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static int alreadyLog = 0;

private TextView nomNavHeader;

public String playMsgId;
private Button home;

private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;

private boolean isMobile = false;

@BindView(R.id.backgroundView1)
ImageView mBack1;

@BindView(R.id.backgroundView2)
ImageView mBack2;

private ValueAnimator animator;
private float mProgressValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)){
        isMobile = true;
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
    else
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.parents_main_space);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    //FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("My first Android non-fatal error"));

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    //po
    SharedPreferenceHelper sharedPreferenceHelper1 = new SharedPreferenceHelper(getApplicationContext());
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View navHeaderView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
    nomNavHeader = (TextView) navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.UserName_nav_header);
    nomNavHeader.setText(sharedPreferenceHelper1.getSharedPreference().getString(KEY.FIRST_NAME,"DEFAULT"));

}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

        mFragment = null;

     if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
         getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Edukily");
         mFragment = mFragmentChat;
         fm.beginTransaction()
                 .remove(mFragmentListChild).commit();



    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
         fm.beginTransaction()
                 .remove(mFragmentChat).commit();
         if (mFragmentListChild == null)
             setupFragmentListChild();

        mFragment=mFragmentListChild;


     } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        ParentSpaceListChild l =new ParentSpaceListChild();
         fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.drawer_layout,l ).commit();
    } else  if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
         // Handle the camera action
         resetIfLogin();




    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        if (mFragmentMyAccount == null)
            setupFragmentMyAccount();

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.my_account);
        mFragment = mFragmentMyAccount;


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        if (mFragmentMyFamily == null)
            setupFragmentMyFamily();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.my_family);
        mFragment = mFragmentMyFamily;
    }

    if (mFragment != null) {
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.root_frame_parents, mFragment).commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return false;
}
}
```

mainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.edukily.fragments.parents.ParentSpaceListChild"
    android:id="@+id/names_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_parents_list_child" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

logcut

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.edukily, PID: 8747
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.edukily/com.edukily.activities.ParentSpace.ParentSpaceMainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                  at com.edukily.activities.ParentSpace.ParentSpaceMainActivity.onCreate(ParentSpaceMainActivity.java:164)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                  at com.edukily.activities.ParentSpace.ParentSpaceMainActivity.onCreate(ParentSpaceMainActivity.java:164) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'backgroundView1' with ID 2131689740 for field 'mBack1' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.
                  at butterknife.internal.Finder.findRequiredView(Finder.java:62)
                  at butterknife.internal.Finder.findRequiredViewAsType(Finder.java:74)
                  at com.edukily.activities.ParentSpace.ParentSpaceMainActivity_ViewBinding.<init>(ParentSpaceMainActivity_ViewBinding.java:18)
                  at com.edukily.activities.ParentSpace.ParentSpaceMainActivity_ViewBinder.bind(ParentSpaceMainActivity_ViewBinder.java:13)
                  at com.edukily.activities.ParentSpace.ParentSpaceMainActivity_ViewBinder.bind(ParentSpaceMainActivity_ViewBinder.java:10)
                  at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:125)
                  at com.edukily.fragments.parents.ParentSpaceListChild.onCreateView(ParentSpaceListChild.java:160)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1065)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1370)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:376)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                  at com.edukily.activities.ParentSpace.ParentSpaceMainActivity.onCreate(ParentSpaceMainActivity.java:164) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Error aboutTogetMinusPoints : no log found Exception @Popo Kori 
Have you posted your log?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'backgroundView1' with ID 2131689740 for field 'mBack1' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.

Comment: I added my logcut @Charuka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your xml layout:

```
<fragment
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.edukily.fragments.parents.ParentSpaceListChild"
android:id="@+id/names_fragment"
android:layout_weight="1"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_parents_list_child" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Error generate in android.support.design.widget.NavigationView it does not support older android versions for this reason app crashes with above error.

there  are 2 drawable.xml file generate in project. when you create drawable

files in drawable.xml(v.21),it does not support older android version.

Do not put your drawable xml files in drawable.xml(v.21).

remove all xml files from this folder and put it drawable.xml